# UnityでのAdMob実装について

Tags: unity3d, admob

Unity5.3を使って、AdMobを実装しようと思っています。
iOSデバイスでは上手く機能しているのですが、Androidではコンパイルエラーになってしまいます。

やったことは、
(1) AdMob管理画面からAndroid用のユニットIDを取得して広告を表示したいソースにコピー
(2) AdMob Unityプラグインをプロジェクトにインポート
(3) Android SDKにインストールされているgoogle-play-services_libをAssets/Plugins/Android/配下にコピー

CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. See the Console for details.

似たようなエラーについての質問とその回答は幾つか見つけることができましたが、解決には至りませんでした（情報が古いためかもしれません）。

Android上でAdMobを実装するためには、上記の手順以外にも何か必要な点があるのでしょうか？
ご教示いただけると幸いです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

Assets\PlayServicesResolver\Editor にある AdMobDependencies.cs　の中に

svcSupport.DependOn("com.android.support", "appcompat-v7", "23.1.0+");

と記述されている箇所を

svcSupport.DependOn("com.android.support", "appcompat-v7", "LATEST");

と書き替えたら、私の場合はうまくいきました。

Comment: アドバイスをありがとうございます。
試してみたのですが、上手くいきませんでした。
結局、コンパイルは通るようになりました。
Asset/Plugins/Android/ 配下にあった５つのファイルを削除してから再ビルドしたらエラーが消えました。

・appcompat-v7-23.1.1.aar
・play-services-ads-8.4.0.aar
・play-services-basement-8.4.0.aar
・support-annotations-23.1.1.jar
・support-v4-23.1.1.aar

しかし、エミュレータ上での実行時に落ちてしまうため、正しい対処法であるかどうかはわからないままです。

Comment: support-v4-23.1.1.aarとsupport-annotations-23.1.1というのが自動で追加されるようになったようですね。
上記５つのファイルは私は残してビルドしましたがうまくいっています、もしかしたらですけど、FaceBookのSDKなどでandroid-support-v4.jarのようなファイルが一緒にインポートされていることがあります、そのようなファイルがあった場合消してみてはどうでしょうか。見当違いなことを言ってしまっていたらすいません。

Comment: それらのファイルを残したままビルドが成功しているんですね。私の場合はダメです。android-support-v4.ja‌​rみたいなファイルを探してみたのですが見当たりませんでした。